# text file content issue

Tags: ios, swift

So, I'm making an importing system to bring text files from email into the app to read there contents. I am very new to swift, and app programming at that (mainly do backend), and I am having an issue with the code below. It is most likely very inefficient and there is probably a better way to do this, but currently I have the `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` with some other code to assign variables to the URL to send to the view controller (haven't worked with notifications/rootviewcontrollers yet). however, after running this code, the result, instead of the contents of the file, is ("matrixFile4197009889-26.text", Unicode (UTF-8)). What should I do? Please explain in "baby language."

My view controller code:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    if delegate.importFileIndicator == true {
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        let docsDirURL = try! filemgr.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let inboxURL = docsDirURL.appendingPathComponent("Inbox")
        print(inboxURL)
        do{
            var directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: inboxURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            var fileSearchBoolCounter = false
            var fileSearchCounter = 0
            var fileURL: URL
            while fileSearchBoolCounter == false {
                if (String(describing: directoryContents[fileSearchCounter].lastPathComponent).range(of: String(describing: NSURL(string: delegate.urlString)!.lastPathComponent!)) != nil) {
                    fileURL = directoryContents[fileSearchCounter]
                    fileSearchBoolCounter = true
                    print(fileURL)
                    let path = inboxURL.appendingPathComponent((NSURL(string: delegate.urlString)?.lastPathComponent!)!)

                    encryptedMessageField.text = try String(contentsOfFile: String(describing: path), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                }else{
                    print(directoryContents[fileSearchCounter])
                    fileSearchCounter += 1
                    print(NSURL(string: delegate.urlString)!.lastPathComponent!)
                }
            }

            delegate.importFileIndicator = false
            fileSearchBoolCounter = false
            fileSearchCounter = 0
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

My AppDelegate code:

```
var importFileIndicator = false
var urlString = ""

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    urlString = String(describing: url)
    print(urlString)
    importFileIndicator = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: 1. You do not want to use `absoluteString` on `url`. It's a file URL. Just work with the URL as-is. 2. What's the point of seeing if `urlString` has an empty prefix? All strings will match. 3. `urlString` is already a `String`. What's the point of the `urlStringVar` variable?

Comment: @rmaddy I corrected all of these things but I am still getting the same result

Comment: Update your question to show your latest code and issues.

Comment: You have at least two issues: `let encryptedFileMessage = (contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` is missing `String`, and `String(describing: encryptedFileMessage)` describes a variable, it doesn't return its contents.

Comment: I made some changes (in the main) and now it says: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “matrixFile4197009889-34.text” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4BCEC0AA-7B1E-4FB2-A410-A91EB162D13C/Documents/Inbox/matrixFile4197009889-34.text, NSUnderlyingError=0x17004fea0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}` but it says the URL is `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4BCEC0AA-7B1E-4FB2-A410-A91EB162D13C/Documents/Inbox/matrixFile4197009889-34.text`

Comment: The error says the file doesn't exist at the same URL the file is in

Comment: All those path/URL/string/... calculations are completely unnecessary. You get a URL in `func application(_ app:, open url:, options:)` and that is all you need to read the file into a String: `let fileContents = try String(contentsOf: url)`. – As a general rule, `String(describing:)` is mostly *not* what you should use for any conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've already good with some parts, but I'm going to include them too in the whole process.

**1. Make your app available to open a TXT file**

To let the system know that your app is prepared to receive a TXT file, you need to configure the `Info.plist` itself, or the simplest way is to configure via `TARGETS/"Info tab"/"Document Types section"`:

[image]

At this point your app becomes available to handle the TXT files coming from other external applications. So when you're about to open a TXT file that is attached to a mail, you should see your app available in the list:

[image]

**2. Prepare app to receive incoming TXT file**

In order to handle the supported file type, you need to implement the `application:openURL:options:` method you've already mentioned in your `AppDelegate`. Here you receive the file path as url, that you can easily send towards your `ViewController` for further processing. This url should looks something like this:

```
(lldb) po url
▿ file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/42D78E58-C7EC-4F3B-9100-B731AF7A4E45/Documents/Inbox/sample.txt
```

**3. Handle the TXT file**

Here you can also store the file's content in a `String` using the appropriate `String` initializer.

```
String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

and then you can pass that `String` to your `ViewController`.

So your `application:openURL:options:` in your `AppDelegate` should looks something like this *(depends on your actual view controller hierarchy)* :

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    do {
        let contentString = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)

        if let window = self.window, let viewController = window.rootViewController as? ViewController {
            viewController.displayText(text: contentString) 
        // here you pass the actual content as String to your custom ViewController which implements a displayText: function that receives a string
        }
    }
    catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
    }

    return true
}
```